# A loop breaking when two consecutive outputs are the same

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float x, y;
    while (true)
    {
    cin >> x;
    if (x == y)
        break;
    y = x;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

This is my loop that is supposed to break after two consecutive numbers entered are the same. I've got two questions I'd appreciate some help with.

Firsty, does this look like the most efficient way of solving the task?

Secondly, is it ok that x and y have no values assigned when declared (`float x=?, y=?`)? Specifically, when the loop is entered for the first time, shouldn't `y` have some value in order to be compared with `x` (`x == y`)?

Comment: first time, y is not initialized. You should set a flag for the first time to avoid comparing to uninitialized.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Could you give me some details? I'm afraid I've never heard about flags as I'm a really a beginner in programming.

Comment: i mean a boolean like "first_input = True;"

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on what you mean by "efficient". It's not the most efficient in the sense of "uses the least possible amount of CPU at runtime", but that hardly matters if the program spends 99.999% of its time waiting for user input.
2. No, you're right. It's a problem that `y` is uninitialized (in general, using an uninitialized variable is an error in your code). You'll have to restructure your logic to account for that.

If you just want your code to be shorter or simpler, you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float x, y;
    std::cin >> y;
    while (std::cin >> x && x != y) {
        y = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, could the program be simpler? I'd be grateful for any suggestions as I see even this early that the variety of possible approaches is what makes programming really interesting.

Comment: One more question, how does it work when  cin is in the while condition? Does it have some boolean value assigned?

Comment: @Theta The boolean value of `cin >> x` is whether a number was successfully read into `x`.

Comment: And it keeps being asked as if it were in the body of while? The advantage is that you have some values of    y and    x before the condition    x    !=    y is checked, but the first    cin had to be outside the loop, right?

Comment: @Theta After execution reaches the end of the body of a `while` loop, it jumps back to the condition. If the condition is false, it jumps out of the loop, otherwise it repeats the body again. And yes, that's why the first input is before the loop.

Comment: My real task is such that I have some more conditions of the `while` loop, that's why it would be more convenient if I had no `cin`s outside the loop. Do you think that my initial approach including what has already been suggested here would be the simplest solution then?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing looks fine (except the lack of initial values). There are many ways of achieving the same result, but stack overflow is not a discussion site. About the initial values, you're right, you should have some. A simple rewriting of your code:

```
int main()
{
   float x=1;
   float y=2;
   bool firstLoop=true; // it is possible that the user first inputs the number 2. To avoid the loop ending before the user inputs the first 2 numbers we use this flag
   while (true)
   {
          cin >> x;

          if (x == y && !firstLoop)
              break;
          y = x;
          firstLoop=false;
   }
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still curious if you can think of some simpler approach without booleans?

Comment: I added an other answer

Answer (score 1):

An other method would be:

```
int main()
{
   float x=0;
   cin >> x;
   cin >> y; 
   while(x!=y){
        x=y; //x will always be the previously entered number
        cin >> y;  //y will always be the newly entered number


   }
   return 0;   
}
```

EDIT: there was a small mistake in the answer, it has been edited out

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you also tell me if you think that the method I suggested including your corrections would be the best if I want no cins outside the loop?